# I have annotated my model with [JsonProperty("file_list")] but the directive is not followed

Tags: c#, json

Im using

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

As you can see in my code further down I've annotated my model with [JsonProperty(“file_list”)] but the directive is not followed
as Swagger UI still thinks it should be called.

> "fileList": [
>         {
>           "containerName": "string",
>           "fileName": "string"
>         }

My code:

```
    [JsonProperty("file_list")] 
    public IEnumerable<FileListViewModel> FileList { get; set; }
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

[edit] Well I know how I am going to fix it. I'm just going to give my viewmodel name file_list. But I was curious why it seems to go wrong by just using annotation.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @fredrik.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Are you using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore? Later versions of it use System.Text.Json by default, so you need to opt-in to Newtonsoft.Json so it will inspect your model annotations appropriately: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

Alternatively, use the System.Text.Json serializer attributes such as `[JsonPropertyName]`.

Comment: @MartinCostello Thanks! I used the System.Text.Json and that worked! And yes I was using     <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.4.1" />.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp .NET Core 3.1  [switched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) from using `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` so either use [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) from `System.Text.Json`:

```
[JsonPropertyName("file_list")] 
public IEnumerable<FileListViewModel> FileList { get; set; }
```

Or opt-in for `Newtonsoft.Json` adding [services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project) in your services configuration (possibly you will need to setup it for swagger also).

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked. Upvoted your answer but because my reputation is too low. It won't show.

Comment: @Triodefreak and was glad to help!